# What type of Doctor was Edwin?

Tags: predator-series, predators-2010

In the movie [*Predators*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1424381/), Edwin claims to be a Doctor.

He has extensive knowledge of a poisonous plant, which he easily identifies at first glance.

> Archaefructus liaoningensis. That is really, really poisonous.
>   Wouldn't take more than one scratch to cause total paralysis.

This led me to believe that he was some sort of botanist.  However, the [wiki](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Edwin) states that he normally carries a medical kit (which I do not recall being mentioned or shown in the movie) and a scalpel.  This information led me to believe that he might be a Medical Doctor.

> Edwin normally carries a medical kit that contains a scalpel which he
>   later coats in the toxin of a plant that Nikolai found

The scalpel that the wiki is referring to appears to be a pocket knife of some sort as seen in Edwin's right hand as he is extracting the toxin from the plant:

[image: Edwin extracting toxin from Archaefructus liaoningensis]

**What type of Doctor was Edwin?  Is this ever explained?**

Comment: Just seems like an old fashioned intellectual to me. :/

Comment: As soon as I saw this in HNQ with the capital D in Doctor, I guessed it was you :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor This made HNQ?  Woot!  Hey...we nurses always capitalize "Doctor"  force of habit ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a deleted scene he claims to have been a surgeon although it's not clear whether his entire "doctor" persona is a complete fabrication.

---

Interestingly, in the [Draft Script](https://web.archive.org/web/20170710224527/http://www.joblo.com/scripts/predators.pdf) the character of Edwin claims to have been an insurance salesman who just happens to be a know-it-all about the subject of neurotoxins, ancient flora and field trauma medicine because he "*reads a lot*". The fact that he's so assured with a scalpel gives the game away (that he's more than meets the eye) far earlier in the script.

> **EDWIN:** *I sell life insurance.*
>
> **STANS:** *Yeah? How about you write me a policy?*
>
> [He chuckles. Edwin doesn’t.]
>
> **EDWIN:** *I’m afraid that would be a poor investment.*

Somewhere along the line the writers seem to have realised how incredibly unlikely all of those skills and knowledge would be in an 'everyman' and made him into a surgeon, then finally into a [generic doctor](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OmnidisciplinaryScientist) in the edit.